# AngularDart Text Area Safe HTML String editor

Tags: html, escaping, dart, angular-dart

On my AngularDart application I have an small / simple text with size limitation (160 chars)
I can display html string and the remaining chars with :

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description"  ng-model="consent.inputDescription" rows="3"></textarea>
<p>Remaining chars: {{consent.getRemainingChars()}}</p>
```

It doesn't work with html chars likes `\&\egrave;`

The `ng-bind-html` directive can display html strings properly but the string inside the controller isn't interpreted, so I can't properly compute the remaining chars

On AngularJS the Strict Contextual Escaping services `($sce)` is usefull for doing this job. I didn't find it in AngularDart. Is there a similar implementation with AngularDart ?

Comment: Have you tired getting the length of the inner text? Inner text is usually unescaped.

Comment: I not satisfied yet by the behavior of my widget. In my editor, the text is written unescaped, but stored escaped by the backend, and displayed later in a textarea. I get the length with this a DOM inspect :
textarea = _shadowRoot.query('#description');
int nbChars = maxChars-textarea.value.length;

Answer (score 2):

This implementation works, waiting better :-/ 
Maybe AngularDart could simplify this code.

I catch all the events of my input field with

```
//handle text aera events
query("#description")
  ..onChange.listen(handler)
  ..onKeyDown.listen(handler)
  ..onKeyUp.listen(handler)
  ..onCut.listen(handler)
  ..onPaste.listen(handler);
```

So I can compute in the handler the remaining chars

```
void handler(Event event) {
  remainingChars = _getRemainingChars();
}
```

The remaining chars is computed with the textarea value (unsafe)

```
_getRemainingChars() {
  int nbChars = 160-_getUnsafeDescription().length;
  return nbChars;
}
```

I read the edited text with :

```
_getUnsafeDescription(){
  var textarea = _shadowRoot.query('#description');
  return textarea.value;
}
```

The text area is bind with html content

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description"  ng-bind-html="consent.inputDescription" rows="3"></textarea>
<p ng-if="consent.remainingChars">Remaining chars: {{consent.remainingChars}}</p>
```

The unsafe edited string post, escaped and stored in the backend